# imageView.setImageBitmap image blank (Android 4.4)

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView which I want to populate from a jpg file (a photo). I first check that the file exists, then load the ImageView using setImageBitmap, but the ImageView remains blank. I have dumped the logcat and there are no exceptions raised. I have also debugged the code to check that the image file exists, and it does). I'm testing on a Galaxy S4, running Android 4.4.2. The image file in question is on an external SD card, so I have the android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission set in my AndroidManifest.

I've read a bunch of other references to this type of problem, both in StackOverflow and elsewhere. One of them suggested adding imageView.invalidate() AFTER setImageBitmap, which I tried (see below), but it didn't help. Does anyone have any other ideas?

In the code below, the debugger shows the imageLocation string having this value:
/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/12345.jpg.

```
    File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);
    if (imageFile.exists()) {   
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        imageView.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Try removing invalidate() and let me know if it helps. You don't need that call as it's done within setImageBitmap

Comment: Might be bitamp is null so try to check bitamp value.

Comment: I've removed the invalidate() and it didn't help. I also now check for (bm !=null) before setImageBitmap and the bitmap isn't null. ???

Comment: Check your image size. May be it can be too large and unable to decode!!

Comment: will you please show proparties of ImageView on your xml file ??

Answer (score 2):

if your code is in `onCreate()` method of Activity it will not work.

Just put that code in any other events like Button`s Click event, the image will appear:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:onClick="ShowImage"/>
```

simply write a method in your Activity as below:

```
public void ShowImage(View view)
{
     File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);
     if (imageFile.exists())
     {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
     }
}
```

It works when I code.
I hope it works for you as well. :-)